# Changing the behavior of CSS clear property?

Tags: css

I have **2** div(s) that they have been floated to left.(At the left bottom)

I have done the following code for the **2nd** div:

```
#div2
{
 float:left;
 clear:left;
}
```

here the clear property forces the **2nd** div to **go down** because div1 is also floated to left.

Is it possible make the 2nd div **go upper** than div1 when clear property is set?

Thanks

***edit(added screenshot):***

[image]

Comment: It would be better if you give the code or screenshot atleast

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation,I did it :D

Comment: I think you mean ***behavior*** by performance. It's confusing by using performance here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is fundamental box-model behavior. Part of the [definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) of 'clear' is that nodes clear *down*. There are a variety of strategies (JS, various positioning hacks) for putting things in an order different from how they appear in markup, but the best strategy is to just rearrange your markup.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible, `#div2` comes after `#div1` so it will always follow it whether vertically or horizontally (when both are floating).

The only solution here is to move `#div2` before `#div1` in the document, whether in the HTML or by manipulating them with Javascript.

Comment: If i do this only their place will change.I want the div 2 to even go upper than div1

Answer (score 0):

no, It is not possible as has already been explained by previous answers

If you want to switch the divs you can try this fiddle that change the `display` css property

http://jsfiddle.net/S4975/1/

```
.div2
{
   display: table-header-group;

}
.div1{
  display: table-footer-group;
}
```

html

```
<div class="div1">A</div>
<div class="div2">B</div>
```

in this way who has `display: table-header-group` will render before elements with display: `table-footer-group;`

refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)